# Can you store form selections in Google Analytics?

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics

If I have a javascript form that toggles lots of buttons on or off, if I want to capture the buttons that were pressed, could I do this in google analytics?, or is it something I would need store in my own database?... if it is possible in GA, can someone point me in the right direction?... kind regards J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on the GA event tracking: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

It'll let you push custom events or actions to GA. So for example:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'AJAXForms', 'Submit', 'Contact details form']);
```

This just records that the form has been submitted, but you can dive a bit deeper in to it to try recording specific values if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yep!

Basically you just bind push command (via jQuery or whatever) to whatever events you want to setup.

```
$('.checkbox').change(function(){
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Checkbox', 'interteraction', $(this).val()]);
});
```

See here for more info..
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Actions

Comment: Please excuse my poor spelling and contrived example  :P

Comment: Thanks Jon, Sadly Nathan answered 2 mins faster than you...! thanks for the reponse, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add entries to the Analytics data queue by using the `push` function, documented on the [Analytics documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#Syntax), together with [custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) or [events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide).